# How does the Sachs-Wolfe effect confirm the existence of dark energy?

Tags: redshift, dark-energy, filaments

How is the Sachs–Wolfe effect and the existence of voids significant in providing physical evidence for dark energy?

Comment: "Void (astronomy) - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_(astronomy)

Comment: I've rephrased your question because the source you cite does not use "proves" or anything like it. Have you tried reading https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3695 and  https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04075 (the two citations on Wikipedia) ...

Comment: @DaveTheWave your question would indeed greatly gain attraction if you tried to understand the sources James linked and point out in what way you don't follow or where you have doubts. Show us that and what you tried yourself to find an answer.

Comment: I looked at the arxiv papers  . I understand what is going on now. Photons entering voids gain energy and blueshift and on exiting the void don't lose the energy gained and  redshift an equal amount because dark energy has moved surrounding galaxies further away weakening gravity. Although I suppose electrons from hot gas clouds in voids could be passing energy to photons if the electrons move in a preferred direction.

Answer (score 2):

The effect being discussed is the [late-time integrated Sachs-Wolfe (ISW) effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachs%E2%80%93Wolfe_effect#Late-time_integrated_Sachs%E2%80%93Wolfe_effect). The idea is that, whilst travelling towards us, cosmic microwave background photons gain energy as they fall into the gravitational potential well of a supercluster and then lose energy as they exit that potential. Conversely, photons travelling into a "cosmic void", experience a higher gravitational potential and lose energy. They then gain energy when they leave the void.

If the CMB photons gain energy, the CMB would appear a little hotter and if they lose energy, the CMB appears colder. If there was an imbalance between the energy gain and energy loss processes as photons propagate, then this might be detectable by looking for correlations between fluctuations in the CMB temperature across the sky and large scale structure (LSS) (i.e. concentrations/voids of matter) in the local universe.

The key point is, that in an expanding universe that is "flat", but which is explained by the matter density being just sufficient to halt the expansion at late times (i.e. an [Einstein de Sitter universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Sitter_universe) with $\Omega_M = 1$), then the amounts of energy that are being gained/lost as photons enter a supercluster/void are *exactly balanced* by the amount of energy lost/gained as they exit the supercluster/void and so no ISW effect would be expected. This is because the density perturbations would grow at exactly the same rate as the scale factor of the universe and there would be no evolution of the gravitational potential.

However, we know that while the universe *is* almost exactly flat, this is not because $\Omega_M=1$, it is that $\Omega_M + \Omega_\Lambda = 1$. But in this case the *accelerating expansion* of the universe, due to the dark energy term, means that the potential wells and hills attributable to superclusters and voids *do* evolve and are somewhat smoothed out during the time it takes a photon to traverse them and the CMB photons will therefore pick up a small amount of energy as they traverse a supercluster and lose a little energy as they traverse a void, resulting in hot and cold spots in the CMB respectively. Note that this is in addition to the usual expansion-associated redshift effects expected.

> Then within the framework of general relativity, any detection of the ISW effect [in a flat universe] would serve as a smoking gun of dark energy.
> ([Dong et al. (2021)](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/500/3/3838/5928561).

Therefore my original sceptical response to the wording of your question was a bit misplaced. The detection of a significant ISW effect would be *really* strong evidence for the existence of dark energy (e.g., [Raccanelli 2011](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/280/1/012009/pdf) uses the word "proof"), though other explanations are possible - a problem with General Relativity for example or more exotic physics ([Multamaki & Elgaroy 2004](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full/2004/33/aa1104/aa1104.right.html)).

Comment: Fair enough I deleted it!